# Show to report viewer group on the top (c#)

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reportviewer

I am using a Report viewer in a C# application.

Currently group shows on the left side of the Tablix.

For example:(region is the group)

```
    Country  population    

Asia   |China |987979799
       |Korea |44354334
       |Nepal |543535353
Europe |France|987979799
       |Germany|44354334
       |England|543535353
```

.
.
.

Is there a way to display the group on the top instead of on the side?

```
         Asia
   |China |987979799
   |Korea |44354334
   |Nepal |543535353
         Europe 
   |France|987979799
   |Germany|44354334
   |England|543535353
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your report is a table and you have it grouped by Continent it will look something like this at the moment.

[image]

And your output will look something like this.[image]

1. From here, right click on the ContinentDesc cell and do `Insert Row
   -> Inside Group- Above`
2. Now delete the first column as we won't need it
3. Next merge the two cells directly above the data cells (select both cells, right click and `Merge`)
4. Select ContinentDesc from the field drop down in the merged cell
5. Centre the cell
6. Optionally delete the header row

You design will now look something like this
[image]

Your output should look something like this

[image]

Hope this helps..

Comment: Your answer seems promising. +1.

Comment: I will test it soon.

Comment: Took me a bit longer to test as I  have 2 child groups. Works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: I've managed to put the grouping on top but I'm having trouble with my inner grouping since it's taking up the whole first column. Any ideas?

Comment: @Doom5 Post a new question. You can add a link back to this question but you need to describe your exact problem. Post screen shots as that will help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with using Tablix, but it seems to me you should be be doing grouping on **Continent** and then have a sub report with your Country and NumberField columns.
If you are using RDLC report file framework that comes with Visual Studio, I believe you will have to do the filtering yourself in the subreport (have subreport do filter based on passed parameter).

[enter link description here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251765(VS.80).aspx)